# GCD in JS - Maximum call stack exceeded

Tags: javascript, range, greatest-common-divisor

This is my recursive code I wrote to calculate the GCD:

```
function gcd(n1, n2) {
    if(n1<n2) {
        return gcd(n1, n2-n1);
    }
    else if(n2<n1) {
        return gcd(n1-n2,n2);
    }
    else{
        return n1;
    }
}
console.log(gcd(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]));
```

It gives me a Range Error. Any idea why? :(

EDIT:

I removed the stdin and replaced it with random numbers and it worked fine.

I wonder why it didn't work the first time though...

Comment: What is process.argv?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Pay close attention to MCVE

Comment: Assuming this is a Node app, what is the *exact* command line used to run it?

Comment: You are probably calling with one argument zero. Than function will never succeed

Comment: The exact command used to run it was : node "filename" 119 68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function gcd(n1, n2) {
    if(n1<n2) {
        return gcd(n1, n2-n1);
    }
    else if(n2<n1) {
        return gcd(n1-n2,n2);
    }
    else{
        return n1;
    }
}
console.log(gcd(parseInt(process.argv[2]), parseInt(process.argv[3])));
```

I think that JavaScript's type coercion is causing a gotcha. With the original version, I can make it get a call stack overflow error like this:

```
node gcd.js 3 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Always know or check the size of an array you try to access its indices. If you're getting a range error, then it means the array isn't the size you think it is, so step #1 is figuring out why your expectations don't match reality.